# selector c VectorDrawables падает на Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, gradle, vector

Еще не так сильно запылилась новость, про возможность использования векторов в ресурсах, как **7 апреля** вышло обновление для `Android Studio` и иже с ним. Обновление подсосало новую версию **Gradle (2.0)**. В результате у меня приложение падает с воплями на `Resources$NotFoundException` на **PRE-Lollipop** версиях, **но только на тех ресурсах, где вектор использовался в виде стейта в selector**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_like_stroke_24dp"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_like_solid_red_24dp"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Это кастомный чекбокс, ресурс устанавливаю программно через `setButtonDrawable()` и при запуске на PRE-Lollipop версиях получаю большой стейк на выходе. Если в `setButtonDrawable()` подать просто обычный вектор, то все прекрассно работает, за исключением того, что мне это не нужно, так как более нет стейтов на чебкоксе.
 Естественно для работы в векторами в `gradle` файле я указывал необходимые параметры.
С начало по стейку грешил на сам векторный файл, но при установке ресурса `ic_like_stroke_24dp` на прямую в виджет, креш не вызывается.
Вот сами векторы для экспериментов.

```
ic_like_stroke_24dp.xml
```

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="128.0"
    android:viewportHeight="128.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#909090"
        android:pathData="M88.3,16c17.2,0,31.2,13.9,31.2,31.2c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.1,5.7-1.8,11.3-5,16c-3.4,4.6-7.1,8.9-11.1,13L70,109.5c-3.4,3.3-8.8,3.3-12.1,0L24.6,76.2c-4-4.1-7.7-8.4-11.1-13c-3.2-4.7-4.9-10.3-5-16C8.5,29.9,22.5,16,39.8,16c8.5,0,16.5,3.5,22.4,9.6l0.6,0.7c0.5,0.6,1.4,0.8,2.1,0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3l0.6-0.7C71.7,19.5,79.8,16,88.3,16M88.3,8c-8.8,0-17.4,2.9-24.3,8.5C57.1,10.9,48.5,8,39.6,8C18,8,0.5,25.5,0.4,47.2C0.5,54.6,2.8,61.8,7,67.9c3.7,4.9,7.7,9.6,11.9,13.9l33.3,33.3c6.5,6.5,17,6.5,23.4,0L109,81.9c4.3-4.4,8.3-9,11.9-13.9c4.2-6.1,6.5-13.3,6.6-20.7C127.5,25.5,110,8,88.3,8L88.3,8z" />
</vector>
```

и

```
ic_like_solid_red_24dp

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="128.0"
    android:viewportHeight="128.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#ff0000"
        android:pathData="M88.3,8c-8.8,0-17.4,2.9-24.3,8.5C57.1,10.9,48.5,8,39.6,8C18,8,0.5,25.5,0.4,47.2C0.5,54.6,2.8,61.8,7,67.9
    c3.7,4.9,7.7,9.6,11.9,13.9l33.3,33.3c6.5,6.5,17,6.5,23.4,0L109,81.9c4.3-4.4,8.3-9,11.9-13.9c4.2-6.1,6.5-13.3,6.6-20.7
    C127.5,25.5,110,8,88.3,8z" />
</vector>
```

До того, как я обновился у меня в `gradle` были следующие параметры (для Gradle 1.5)

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        generatedDensities = []
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}
```

После обновления Android Studio и Gradle (2.0)  я заменил выше описанное на

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

И отсюда вопрос, куда копать? После обновления ушла возможность использовать вектор в selector. Откатить студию до прошлой версии можно, но не выход.
Стейк:

```
    Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/check_box_like.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004d
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.setButtonDrawable(AppCompatCheckBox.java:74)
       at view.catalogs.CatalogListAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(CatalogListAdapter.java:126)
       at view.catalogs.CatalogListAdapter.getItemView(CatalogListAdapter.java:61)
       at com.culiu.mhvp.core.tabs.GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.createItemRow(GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.java:114)
       at com.culiu.mhvp.core.tabs.GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.getView(GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.java:95)
       at com.culiu.mhvp.core.InnerListView$InflateFirstItemIfNeededAdapter.getView(InnerListView.java:557)
       at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1332)
       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1642)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_like_stroke_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02009d
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
       at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.setButtonDrawable(AppCompatCheckBox.java:74)
       at view.catalogs.CatalogListAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(CatalogListAdapter.java:126)
       at view.catalogs.CatalogListAdapter.getItemView(CatalogListAdapter.java:61)
       at com.culiu.mhvp.core.tabs.GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.createItemRow(GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.java:114)
       at com.culiu.mhvp.core.tabs.GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.getView(GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.java:95)
       at com.culiu.mhvp.core.InnerListView$InflateFirstItemIfNeededAdapter.getView(InnerListView.java:557)
       at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1332)
       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1642)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
       at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.setButtonDrawable(AppCompatCheckBox.java:74)
       at view.catalogs.CatalogListAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(CatalogListAdapter.java:126)
       at view.catalogs.CatalogListAdapter.getItemView(CatalogListAdapter.java:61)
       at com.culiu.mhvp.core.tabs.GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.createItemRow(GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.java:114)
       at com.culiu.mhvp.core.tabs.GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.getView(GridViewWithHeaderBaseAdapter.java:95)
       at com.culiu.mhvp.core.InnerListView$InflateFirstItemIfNeededAdapter.getView(InnerListView.java:557)
       at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1332)
       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1642)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нарвался на новость - https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne частично на время пока можно забыть про векторы.
Проблема решается удалением строки в `gradle`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

Это приведет к увеличению объему апк, за счет конвертации векторов в png.

Comment: конечно если вас такое решение устраивает, то все хорошо.
однако вы без проблем можете откатиться на версию support `23.2.1`, и описанный мной способ поможет :)

Comment: попробую откатиться

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте сначала достать `drawable` и только потом засунуть в чекбокс.

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.selector);
mCheckBox.setButtonDrawable(drawable);
```

На данный момент эта проблема по-другому не обходится. Если хочется красивости, то придется наследоваться от чекбокса или любой другой вьюхи, которая не поддерживает вектора и делать либо так, либо создавать кастомные атрибуты, а внутри использовать способ, представленный выше, чтобы была возможность задавать вектора в xml

Comment: увы это не спасет не в каком виде, я дал ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 2):

У меня получилось запустить vector'ы на `pre-lollipop`. У меня `drawable` (векторы и селекторы) лежали в папке `drawable-anydpi`. Я когда открыл архив `app-debug.apk` - оказалось, что папка `drawable-anydpi-v21`, следовательно работала исключительно на 21 и выше апишках.

В итоге я просто перенес все из папки `drawable-anydpi` в обычную drawable - и все заработало.

```
версия = 23.3.0
```

I have run vectors on `pre-lollipop`. I have `drawable` (vectors and selectors) which location at `drawable-anydpi` folder. When I opened `app-debug.apk` archive - i saw `drawable-anydpi-v21`, which means that drawables can be access only from api 21 devices. I moved all drawables from `drawable-anydpi` to `drawable` - and it works.

```
version of appcompat = 23.3.0
```

---

Update:
ic_account_checked.xml

```
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp">
<path
    android:fillColor="#ffffff"
    android:pathData="M12,19.2C9.5,19.2 7.29,17.92 6,16C6.03,14 10,12.9 12,12.9C14,12.9 17.97,14 18,16C16.71,17.92 14.5,19.2 12,19.2M12,5A3,3 0,0 1,15 8A3,3 0,0 1,12 11A3,3 0,0 1,9 8A3,3 0,0 1,12 5M12,2A10,10 0,0 0,2 12A10,10 0,0 0,12 22A10,10 0,0 0,22 12C22,6.47 17.5,2 12,2Z"
    />
```

ic_account_default.xml

```
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp">
<path
    android:fillColor="#7fffffff"
    android:pathData="M12,19.2C9.5,19.2 7.29,17.92 6,16C6.03,14 10,12.9 12,12.9C14,12.9 17.97,14 18,16C16.71,17.92 14.5,19.2 12,19.2M12,5A3,3 0,0 1,15 8A3,3 0,0 1,12 11A3,3 0,0 1,9 8A3,3 0,0 1,12 5M12,2A10,10 0,0 0,2 12A10,10 0,0 0,12 22A10,10 0,0 0,22 12C22,6.47 17.5,2 12,2Z"
    />
```

ic_account_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_account_checked" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_account_default" />
```

И теперь где используется (where it using):

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_news"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/pressable_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/pressable_size"
            android:checked="true"
            android:button="@drawable/ic_account_selector"
            />
```

Проверил на api 18, 19. (Check it on api 18-19)

Comment: я не делил на версии. векторы изначально хранились в drawable

Comment: @Chaynik обновил ответ. А вообще посмотри как ты извлекаешь drawable для кастомной view. Тебе по идеи в attrs.xml нужно указать:
`<attr name="srcImage" format="reference"/>`
А в самом классе получить drawable через 
`TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView);
mButtonDrawable = array.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomView_srcImage);`

Comment: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector

Comment: Все тоже самое. сделал все также как Вы указали, более того это сделано в чистом проекте,

Comment: Вы используете         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
в gradle?

Comment: @Chaynik нет, этого не использую. Скинь свою версию gradle (корневой build.gradle) -  у меня стоит classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta1'

Comment: @Chaynik а вообще открой архив с приложением и посмотри, где у тебя сгенеренные drawable и есть ли они вообще, я от этого отталкивался.

Comment: Если Вы НЕ используете vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true в gradle (Gradle plugin 2.0), то Вы не ответили на мой вопрос. Так как суть вопросы была именно в использовании векторов. У вас же идет конвертация векторов в png при сборке. В таком случае ваш ответ ничем не отличается от моего, только вы не указали суть.

Comment: @Chaynik прошу прощения, по вопросу не особо понятно в чем суть. как я понял, это вообще работа с векторами. 
от твоего ответа действительно отличий нету.  насчет откатов до 23.2.1 - у меня этот флаг на этой версии не работал.

Answer (score 0):

В каждом  Activity, где используются векторные ресурсы нужно добавить:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```